# iCloud Mail doesn't load, but all other iCloud services work fine

Tags: email, icloud

I've been having this weird problem with iCloud for a while.

If I go to `icloud.com`, I can login just fine, and everything works (Contacts, Calendars, etc.), EXCEPT the Mail app. Whenever I click the Mail Icon, I get this error:

[image]

When I click "Report to Apple" it gives a more detailed log, ending with this message:

```
Sat, 24 Dec 2011 04:13:07 GMT:  ERROR: CoreMail handled error 13002 before exiting Mail
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

By the way, whenever I try to login to Mail in the Mac OS X Mail.app or the iPhone mail, I get `The iCloud IMAP server “p06-imap.mail.me.com” rejected the password for user “myusernamehere”`
, even though the password is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a temporary problem, as it now appears fixed.

Comment: Not quite fixed yet because I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Phillip: you're not the first to post that here. In my experience iCloud email is just too flaky for actual use right now, I stopped using iCloud for email.